# Umbraco pulling media files from incorrect folder

Tags: file, directory, media, umbraco

I'm running Umbraco 4.8.0 via WebMatrix 2 on a local SQL server 2008 R2. Everything works fine except for when I try to upload media images via the Media tab. I get

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find a part of the path '\C:\xxxxxxxx\media\id\picture.png'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '\C:\xxxxxxxx\media\id\picture.png'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '\markerstudy.local\data\Users\sirwin\My Web Sites\caabWebsite\media\109\bg-red-centre.png'.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +224
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath) +1142
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) +83
   System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes) +86
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Files.UmbracoFile.Save(Byte[] file, String fullFileName) +323
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.Files.UmbracoFile.Save(Stream inputStream, String fullFileName) +188
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype.FileHandlerData.set_Value(Object value) +404
   umbraco.editorControls.uploadField.Save() +369
   umbraco.controls.ContentControl.saveClick(Object Sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) +158
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +120
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Umbraco creates another media folder elsewhere in the system and saves the image there. When I copy the folder over (the ID numbered folder), I can then upload the image in Umbraco without a problem.

Is there a way to make Umbraco point to the correct media folder in my computer by default?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are expecting these files not to be saved into the website?

They're always saved under the /media folder in the root directory of your website, unless you've changed a config setting.
The point of this is if you don't necessarily have admin (or folder) rights to part of a remote web server, Umbraco will still let you upload images to the site & utilise them.